# Python maths quiz alphabetical sorting

Tags: python-3.x

I'm struggling to get my code to work on python it is meant to print the data in alphabetical order but doesn't can anyone help?

```
if choice.lower() == 'az':
            dictionary={}
            fi = open("class1.txt",'r')
            data = fi.readlines()
            for line in sorted(data):
                print(data.rstrip());
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: why are you printing `data` and not `line`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use readlines here, `sorted` is able to iterate over the file just fine. You should be printing `line.strip()` instead of `data.strip()`

```
with open("class1.txt",'r') as fi:
    for line in sorted(fi):
        print(line.rstrip())
```

I've also shown you how to use a context manager here (the `with` line). This causes the file to be closed automatically at the end of the block

Answer (score 0):

You're applying rstrip wrong:

```
print(line.rstrip());
```

should do the trick.